# flexboxで要素の高さが揃わない

Tags: html, css, sass

### 解決したいこと

cssでコーディングをしているのですが、flexboxで要素の高さが揃わないです

### 状況

下記のコードがHTMLです。

```
<div class="plans-content">
  <div class="plans-content-item">
    <h3 class="plans-content-title">タイトル1</h3>
    <div class="plans-content-detail">
    <div class="plans-content-detail-title">
      詳細タイトル1
    </div>
    <div class="plans-content-detail-list">
      <ul>
        <li class="content-detail-list-item">アイテム1</li>
        <li class="plans-content-detail-list-item">アイテム2</li>
        <li class="plans-content-detail-list-item">アイテム3</li>
        <li class="plans-content-detail-list-item">アイテム4</li>
        <li class="plans-content-detail-list-item">アイテム5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="plans-content">
  <div class="plans-content-item">
    <h3 class="plans-content-title">タイトル1</h3>
    <div class="plans-content-detail">
    <div class="plans-content-detail-title">
      詳細タイトル1
    </div>
    <div class="plans-content-detail-list">
      <ul>
        <li class="content-detail-list-item">アイテム1</li>
        <li class="plans-content-detail-list-item">アイテム2</li>
        <li class="plans-content-detail-list-item">アイテム3</li>
        <li class="plans-content-detail-list-item">アイテム4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

上の要素を

```
<div class="plans-contents"></div>
```

というHTMLで囲っています

CSSは

```
.plans-contents {
  display: flex;
}

.plans-content {
  display: flex;
}

// リストを縦方向に並べる
.plans-content-detail-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

としたのですが、
`<div class="plans-content-detail-list">` で囲まれた領域がliタグの数によって伸び縮みしてしまいます。（下記の画像参照）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

flexboxを使っているので、 `<div class="plans-content-detail">` で囲まれた領域の高さが同じになるのはわかるのですが、その中身の高さが揃わないので困っています。

教えてください、

Answer (score 1):

下記でどうでしょうか。

```
.plans-contents {
  display: flex;
}

.plans-content {
  display: flex;
}

.plans-content-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.plans-content-detail {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.plans-content-detail-list {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

`.plans-content-detail-list`に`height: 100%;`として、親要素からはみ出した部分を`overflow: hidden;`で隠すという手法です。